# Eigenvalues of a matrix with repeating elements

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Given a sequence $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, consider the matrix $H_{ij} = a_{\min(i, j)}$. What can be said about its eigenvalues? Can they all be calculated?

To add an example, consider the sequence $a, b, c, d$ which generates the matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
a & a & a & a \\
a & b & b & b \\
a & b & c & c \\
a & b & c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

In case where $a = a_1 = \ldots = a_n$ I know the eigenvalues are $na, 0, \ldots, 0$, but in the other cases I have no clue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also working on this type of matrices, called MIN matrices.

There is no closed form expression for the eigenvalues.

However, you can find many interesting properties of MIN matrices like Factorization, determinant, inversion,... in this paper (Mattila & Haukkanen, 2016, Studying the various properties of MIN and MAX matrices - elementary vs. more advanced methods).

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't have any idea there was a name for such matrices.